# How to make the keyboard media keys to work with VLC globally?

Tags: unity, multimedia, vlc

My keyboard has media keys and they work globally on Unity with Banshee but don't with VLC when another app is focused.

How would I fix that?

Comment: Simply you need to restart VLC to make the settings take effect!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had a similar problem and the issue was that Gnome would capture the media keys before they reached VLC, to fix this you can go to "System->Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts"

There you will see a header called sound (Expand it if needed), and remove the key combinations you want in VLC from there (You can disable them by clicking on the item and then pressing backspace).

Only problem with this is that any other applications that do use Gnome's built-in handling won't work anymore with the media keys, unless you add them again (Which in turn breaks VLC again)

Comment: I don't know why, but I had also to restart the computer to make it recognize global keys,

Comment: For me it was enough to restart VLC.

Comment: Just re-emphasizing, you have to REMOVE the bindings. And this is NOT the VLC preferences, it's the operating system keyboard settings. More verbose info here:
https://major.io/2015/02/20/using-playpause-buttons-in-chrome-with-gnome-3/

Answer (score 13):

VLC comes with configurable hotkey definitions. To access the hotkey menu open *Tools -> Preferences -> Hotkeys*:

[image]

The key for a given action can be determined by clicking on the line in between *Clear* and *Apply*. Then a window pops up to ask you for the new key combination. Press *Apply* to save these.

This procedure works fine with standard keyboard keys. However depending on keyboard hardware layout multimedia keys may not be recognized correctly ([bug #419795](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vlc/+bug/419795), [Videolan Support](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=38250), [Videolan on Ubuntu 10.10](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=86524))

Comment: Unfortunately that won’t be enough while GNOME still intercepts those keys. You need to disable them in the system settings.

Comment: I would set it to "global" instead of "hotkeys", so I can still play/pause with a spacebar inside VLC. Then as @Bombe said also disable the keys in system settings.

Comment: And restart VLC

Answer (score 10):

I use Ubuntu 14.04(64-bit) and VLC 2.1.5

In VLC, go to ***Tools > Preferences > Hotkeys***.
You will find three columns ***Action, HotKey, Global***.

See the image uploaded by the user *Takkat*.

Click on the ***Global*** column[Next to the ***HotKey*** column] corresponding to the ***Action*** you seek, enter the media key combination and click ***Save***.

Restart VLC.

Comment: this is the correct answer to the question as it does not affect other apps - the upvoted answer are systemwide settings.

Comment: one quirk, I had to unset the action in ubuntu system shortcut, then set vlc shurtcut global as Fazil said, and then set ubuntu system shortcut back.

Answer (score 7):

The only workaround I could think of is to add a key modifier, e.g. press an <kbd>Alt</kbd> while pressing the multimedia key. That way the key combination is different from what's captured by GNOME thus it simulates the effect of using multimedia key to control VLC.

I used this only for play/pause (So the key is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+XF86AudioPlay, something like this; in VLC it shows as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+"Media Play Pause").

Answer (score 1):

Here is an updated answer for **Ubuntu 13.10** using **VLC media player 2.0.8**:

In Ubuntu, go to *System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Sound and Media*

Disable the key combinations you want in VLC (by clicking on the item and pressing backspace).

In VLC, go to *Tools > Preferences > Hotkeys*

Set the key combinations you previously disabled to a VLC action in a Global.

You can then set back the keyboard shortcut for the Ubuntu System in order for the other applications that do use Gnome's built-in handling to work. However, when VLC is running, VLC will take precedence over other applications.

EDIT: you may also need to relaunch VLC for the new hotkeys to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by downloading hotkeys in the software centre. I search hotkeys in the software centre and it shows up. It says is A hotkeys daemon for your Internet/multimedia keyboard in X.

First I download it, and than I had to disable the system hotkeys, than set the hotkeys in VLC, finally I enable the system's hotkeys. I can pause, play, and skip with the keyboard even with VLC minimize.

Comment: @salip, Can you please add the steps or a screenshot and help us understand better.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Google Music extension installed in Google Chrome, that will also intercept the media keys. I had to disable the Google Music extension, and then VLC noticed my media keys.