# Control VLC with bluetooth headset

Tags: bluetooth, vlc

I have the S305 Motorola bluetooth headset. I can control other music players (like Audacious or Goggles) from my headset but not VLC.

Is there some way to control VLC with a BT headset?

Comment: Can you use the keyboard multimedia keys? Maybe this is the problem: http://askubuntu.com/a/48398/153260

Comment: Thank you very much for your response Leopoldo but the solution in that question doesn't seem to work. The answer about global hotkeys is interesting but I need it to work even if VLC doesn't have focus (and that didn't seem to work either).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First download some packages

   ```
   sudo apt-get install bluez-utils bluez-gnome bluez-alsa
   ```
2. Find the MAC of the headset

   ```
   sudo hcitool scan
   ```

   The output will look something like this:

   ```
   $ sudo hcitool scan
   Scanning ...
           XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX       Stereo Headset
   ```
3. Setup `~/.asoundrc` file

   ```
   pcm.bluetooth {
           type bluetooth
           device "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX"
           profile "auto"
   }
   ```
4. Reboot

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```
5. Connect Bluetooth Headset
6. Change `alsa-audio-device` in `~/.config/vlc/vlcrc`:

   ```
   gedit ~/.config/vlc/vlcrc
   ```

   Find:

   ```
   # Audio output device (string)
   # alsa-audio-device=default
   ```

   And change it to

   ```
   # Audio output device (string)
   alsa-audio-device=bluetooth
   ```

Hope this help.

Comment: BiggJJ I am accepting your answer because I won't have time to test it before the bounty times out and if it works I want you to get the full bounty. Thank you so much for taking the time to give a step by step and clear answer :)

Comment: @Darin Did you ever try this?

Comment: Not yet but I'll try to make time this weekend. I'm using a different laptop at the moment.